# CA-SCM/Harvest: get package ids during the promote

Tags: harvest-scm

I want to retrieve the list of packages during the promote, e.g. when promote from DEV to QA, and get the list of file inside the package. What's these two commands?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this. Do you want list of lises inside package ? or Get the package ID for promotion. Also what is the API you are using to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using promote process from workbench.

Consider using system variables as post linked process in the promote process
[package] [version]
I am assuming you are executing promote process on package group

This will provide the package(s) list and the versions in these packages.

If you need more details ,please reach out to us in CA harvest communities where visibility is high

https://communities.ca.com/community/ca-harvest

Regards,
Balakrishna

Answer (score 0):

When promoting from dev to qa use the post link process 
for example:

```
scriptName  "[project]" "[state]"
```

In the server put the script (including the select as following )

```
select distinct c.PACKAGENAME , e.ITEMNAME, g.USERNAME, d.MAPPEDVERSION         VERSION, f.PATHFULLNAME
    from HARSTATE a, HARENVIRONMENT b, HARPACKAGE c, HARVERSIONs d, HARITEMs    e, HARPATHFULLNAME f, HARUSER g
where b.ENVOBJID =  a.ENVOBJID
and a.STATEOBJID = c.STATEOBJID
and b.ENVIRONMENTNAME  = '${Project}'
and a.STATENAME        = '${state}'
and c.PACKAGEOBJID = d.PACKAGEOBJID
and d.ITEMOBJID = e.ITEMOBJID
and e.PArentobjid = f.itemOBJID and e.itemtype <> 0
and g.USROBJID=c.CREATORID
and c.packagename != 'BASE'
order by c.packagename  , f.pathfullname
```